# How to define high frequency rainfall?

Tags: rainfall

I have a rainfall data set from a weather station where the data was collected at 20 minutes intervals for 10 years. I would like to peak up the high frequency rainfall cases.

What are such rainfalls? How to know them from a data set?

Comment: Kay - in this context high frequency is a bit ambiguous. When we mention high frequency with respect to rainfall measurement many readers would take that as referring to the frequency with which a measurement is made - 20 minute rainfall data would be considered 'high frequency observations' in comparison to measurements made on daily, weekly or monthly intervals. Do you mean high intensity rainfall? This would be the rainfall events that exceed some threshold in millimetres per hour. What constitutes high intensity depends on the location.

Comment: @AndyM Many thanks for your answer. I mean "high frequency rainfall". So there is nothing like high frequency rainfall case except a close time scale, right?

Comment: It is just  possible that someone might describe frequent rain storms as being "high frequency"?  If so, and again location dependent, it could be counting  something like "months where it rained on at least n days" . Still a rather ambiguous concept.